# Iterating API Calls w/ Response Data Axios

Tags: node.js, api, axios, synchronous

I need to make n # of api calls where n obtained from the response of the first api call and used as parameter in all subsequent calls. What am I missing in the code?

```
var axios = require('axios');

axios.get('url', {
    headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'},
    params: {
      param1 : '1',
      param2 : '2',
      param3 : '3',
      param4 : '4'
    }
  })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
    for(var page_number = 1; page_number <= response.data; page_number++){
      axios.get('url', {
          headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'},
          params: {
            param1 : '1',
            param2 : '2',
            param3 : '3',
            param4 : page_number
          }
        })
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data);
        });
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    });
  }
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });

Thanks for your help!
```

Comment: What is your output right now?  What is `response.data`?  If it's not a length, you're `for` loop will never execute.

Comment: The output is an int.

Comment: Indeed, what are you missing? The question doesn't contain clear problem statement. Consider providing https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate the problem.